# Github can't automatically merge into dev branch

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge my branch task-5 with dev branch but it can't merge automatically. There was conflict, I fixed it and after that I committed it into branch task-5 but I can't still merge.

How should I merge task-5 into dev branch? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps:

```
git checkout task-5
git pull --rebase origin dev
#if everything is ok
git push origin HEAD:dev
```

If it does not work, try again:

```
git fetch origin dev
git checkout -b my_dev FETCH_HEAD
git cherry my_dev task-5
#you will get a list of '+ sha1'. Ignore the '- sha1' lines. 
#Suppose we get 3 sha1's, 1234567,2345678, and 3456789.
git cherry-pick 1234567
git cherry-pick 2345678
git cherry-pick 3456789
#if there is any conflict, fix it
  git add .;git cherry-pick --continue
#fi
git pull --rebase origin dev
git push origin HEAD:dev
```

Comment: What does second solution make? What is this `cherry-pick`?

Comment: `git cherry-pick sha1` makes a commit equivalent to sha1 on the current branch. The new commit has a same diff with its origin, but the commit dates and sha1's are different.